# Accent insensitive string comparison?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there any way to do an accent insensitive string comparison? For example, é == e? I couldn't find any options to pass rangeOfString:options:. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You want to pass the `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch` option to whichever method you use (e.g. `compare:options:` or `rangeOfString:options:`)

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible for me to pass NSCaseInsensitiveSearch and NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch to rangeOfString:options:?

Comment: Yes, OR them together using the | operator. e.g. `NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch`

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate it. I wasn't sure if I should use & or |.

Comment: @Sam: Remember the truth tables: `&` returns a 1 for any bit that was set in both sides, so if you try to combine two different flags with it, you will get 0. `|` returns a 1 for any bit that is set in either side, which is how you can use it to combine flags. You use `&` to test bits in an already-combined mask.

Comment: Does this work with other special symbols in characters? For example Õ == O.

Comment: Interesting that the documentation for `rangeOfString:options:` lists a list of options, and does not include NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch.

Answer (score 0):

If you also want a substring search and have an array of items you want to filter I recommend this:

```
[self.objects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id  _Nullable evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable bindings) {
    MyClass *object = (MyClass *)evaluatedObject;
    if ([object.name localizedStandardContainsString:filterString]) return YES;
    return NO;
}]];
```