# How Do I Compare Two Characters Ignoring Accents And Other Special Symbols?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accent insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610898/accent-insensitive-string-comparison)

I need to compare two different characters, ignoring their accents (if they have any) and any other special symbols.

That being said, if I compare 'É' == 'E' it should give me true as the result (it should treat both characters as the same one). Same if I compare 'Õ' == 'O'.