# Checking if NSMutableArray of names has prefix of multiple characters

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to split contact names into separate `NSMutableArrays` and want to include letters with accents amongst these arrays.

```
if([[contact.givenName lowercaseString] hasPrefix:@"a"]){
        [selectedArray addObject:contact];
        NSLog(@"%@",contact.givenName);
    }
```

The above works fine for the letter "a", but I wish to include the following:

```
@"a",@"á",@"â",@"ã",@"ä"
```

What is the correct way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try with OR operator ?

Comment: You seem to be looking for `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accent insensitive string comparison?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610898/accent-insensitive-string-comparison)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Larme suggested you need to use `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch` like this.

```
if ([contact.givenName length] >= 1) {
    NSString *nameFirstLetter = [contact.givenName substringToIndex:1];
    NSStringCompareOptions options = NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch;
    if([nameFirstLetter compare:@"a" options:options] == NSOrderedSame){
        [selectedArray addObject:contact];
        NSLog(@"%@",contact.givenName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to put `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch` into `options` rather than converting to converting `lowercaseString`? More readable in future, no?

Comment: You still left the `lowercaseString` part for `nameFirstLater` => `NSString *nameFirstLater = [contact.givenName substringToIndex:1];`

Comment: Thanks for the responses, though this resulted in `'*** -[__NSCFConstantString substringToIndex:]: Index 1 out of bounds; string length 0' crash, though @vadian answer has seemed to work, is there any advantage of using this method over his?

Comment: @Manesh You cannot mix this two answer.

Comment: @Manesh: This answer as such doesn't take care of `givenName` empty or nil. You can use `NSPredicate` version that does it, but you may also want to filter theses empty/nil ones beforehand and that would avoid the crash.

Comment: @Manesh Now it will take care of empty String.

Comment: @Manesh Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the array with a predicate, `[cd]` means case and diacritic insensitive.

Assuming `contacts` is the array containing the `contact` instances

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"givenName BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", @"a"];
NSArray *selectedArray = [contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

The solution is very fast, you even don't need a repeat loop and it handles also the case if the property is empty or `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode your string before check :

```
NSString *str = @"ä";
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
if([[newStr lowercaseString] hasPrefix:@"a"]){
    NSLog(@"%@",newStr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch

```
 NSString *string =@"á";
 if ([string rangeOfString:@"a" options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch].location
    != NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog(@"found words");

}
```